# LaTeX: Citation without comma

Tags: latex, citations, biblatex

Currently I am writing a thesis in which I am supposed to cite with `Author YEAR`.

```
\usepackage[natbib=true,bibstyle=authoryear,backend=bibtex8,citestyle=authoryear,uniquelist=false,uniquename=false,maxbibnames=50,maxcitenames=2,sorting=nyt,sortcase=false]{biblatex}
```

I use the `authoryear` style, which according to
https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/biblatex_bibliography_styles
should give me the proper citation style, but it doesn't.

With `\autocite`, `\parencite`, `\cite`, `\citep`, `\textcite` I can only get `Author, YEAR` or variations of that.

Comment: In the future, please don't just post code fragments but make compilable [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by putting natbib=false